# HQL to JPQL question

Tags: hibernate, hql, eclipselink, jpql

What is the translation of the following HQL query to EclipseLink compliant JPQL :

```
select p from NameList list, Person p
where p.name in elements(list.names)
```

(this is just a variation of a HQL example query taken from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html))

In EclipseLink the IN function doesn't seem to take property paths :

```
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(36!=[693:1: inExpression[boolean not, Object left] returns [Object node] : (t= IN n= inputParameter | t= IN LEFT_ROUND_BRACKET (itemNode= inItem ( COMMA itemNode= inItem )* | subqueryNode= subquery ) RIGHT_ROUND_BRACKET );])
```

I could probably solve this with another join, but is there something more compact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
select p from NameList list, Person p
where p.name member of list.names
```

This solution is JPA 2 compliant.